# Did the anime cover all the manga up to Season 4 of Shingeki no Kyojn?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I would like to read the manga after Season 3 Part 2 of the anime *Shingeki no Kyojn*. But I would like to ask if the anime covered the manga chapters before it?

Clarification:
MAIN QUESTION. Did the Anime include all that there is in the manga (at least the chapters up until the last part of Season 3 Part 2 of the anime)?

If not, what are the manga chapters not included so that I could read them before proceeding?

Comment: This question is confusing. Could you clarify what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. *The anime is behind the manga by more than 30 chapters.*

The [last episode](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/To_the_Other_Side_of_the_Wall) of the latest Attack on Titan season adapted **Chapter 90** of the manga so Season 4 would, presumably, start from **Chapter 91**.

It should also be worth noting that [Season 4 is the last season for the anime series](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Attack_on_Titan_(Anime)), given that the manga is already on its final arc.

Comment: Personal advice: read the manga from the start.

Comment: Why exactly? The anime is pretty faithful except for the first Season 3 arc. I guess you should if you wanna see the gore uncensored.

Comment: @Direnta There are differences between the anime and manga, even before Season 3. Whether or not they are minimal is up to the reader/watcher so I won't force anyone. This is just a personal advice, up to the OP whether he/she will take it or not.